# How to implement Nested ListView in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

What is the preferred way to achieve a nested ListView, or in other words, ListView Widgets that could be included within a scrollable parent?

Imagine a "Reports" page, where a section is an itemized list.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you want to have the inner `ListView` be scrollable independently of the main scroll view, you should use [`NestedScrollView`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NestedScrollView-class.html). Otherwise, use a [`CustomScrollView`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html).

Here is some code illustrating the `NestedScrollView` approach.

[image: video]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            new SliverAppBar(
              pinned: true,
              title: new Text('Flutter Demo'),
            ),
          ];
        },
        body: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new FlutterLogo(size: 100.0, colors: Colors.purple),
            new Container(
              height: 300.0,
              child: new ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 60,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return new Text('Item $index');
                },
              ),
            ),
            new FlutterLogo(size: 100.0, colors: Colors.orange),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not scroll the Flutterlogo completly. It stops scrolling. How can I scroll the whole container? I mean that the FlutterLogo is completly invisible?

Comment: The "main" scroll, the Nested, does not scroll at all. Adding more logos at the end, resulted in overflow and not the expected scrolling. Hmm . . .

Answer (score 256):

For child ListView, use that parameter:

```
shrinkWrap: true,
physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me when the child list view is nested in a `scrollBar` nested in a `ScrollConfiguration` nested in a `Container`

Comment: Thanks for the ClampingScrollPhysics() :D

Comment: This works for the nested ListView that is inside of a parent ListView! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, ClampingScrollPhysics() basically adds the length of the nested scrollbar to the entire screen. Very useful, thanks !

Comment: I have used Singlechildscrollview for main page scroll and inside it i have used Container for fix data and after that listview.builder but i want my list view data scroll with my main scroll view not saperated.

Comment: It only works for a specific case, like both parent and child listviews are just normal `ListView(children: [...])`. It fails for `ListView.builder(...)`

Comment: what does this really do?

Comment: there is choppy scroll whent Listview => Listview.Builder

Comment: This breaks the RefreshIndicator for me though.

Comment: Worked for me with `ListView.builder`

Answer (score 53):

Adding `physics: ClampingScrollPhysics()` and `shrinkWrap: true` did the trick for me.

**sample code:**

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: 123,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Parent'),
                    ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: 2,
                        physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(), 
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return Text('Child');
                        }),
                  ],
                );
              }),
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 12):

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

**Code:**

```
var _container = Container(
  height: 200,
  color: Colors.blue,
  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: Text("ListView")),
    body: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
      child: ListView( // parent ListView
        children: <Widget>[
          _container,
          _container,
          Container(
            height: 200, // give it a fixed height constraint
            color: Colors.teal,
            // child ListView
            child: ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (_, i) => ListTile(title: Text("Item ${i}"))),
          ),
          _container,
          _container,
          _container,
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks

Comment: Briliant! Trying to work around fixed height (eg let it expand if there is more room)

Comment: 10 mins later: wrap inner ListView in ConstrainedBox (where specify min/max dims) and shrinkWrap inner list. Bam! Let's see if it works in production.

Answer (score 12):

For inner Listview I have just added below code and it solved for me

```
shrinkWrap: true,
physics: ScrollPhysics(),
```

Comment: When the inner Listview becomes scrollable your code doesn't work.

Answer (score 10):

Thanks to Serdar Polat:

```
ListView.builder( // outer ListView
  itemCount: 4,
  itemBuilder: (_, index) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text('Header $index'),
        ),
        ListView.builder( // inner ListView
          shrinkWrap: true, // 1st add
          physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(), // 2nd add
          itemCount: 10,
          itemBuilder: (_, index) => ListTile(title: Text('Item $index')),
        )
      ],
    );
  },
)
```

Answer (score 4):

shrinkWrap to wrap your content and ClampingScrollPhysics to use the parent scroll

```
ListView.builder(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
    itemCount: yourList.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) => YourWidget(items[index]),
),
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this:

```
scrollController.addListener(onScroll);

void onScroll(){
    if(scrollController.offset == 0.0
        || scrollController.position.extentBefore == 0.0
        || scrollController.position.extentAfter == 0.0){
      scrollPhysics = NeverScrollableScrollPhysics();

      Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), (){
        scrollPhysics = ClampingScrollPhysics();
        setState((){});
      });

      setState((){});;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Use AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics instead of ClampingScrollPhysics.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      itemCount: requestList.length,

                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        int que = index;
                        return Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                    left: 20,
                                    top: 10,
                                    bottom: 10,
                                    right: 20),
                                child: Text(
                                  '${que++} . ${requestList[index].question}',
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14,
                                    color: HexColor(HexColor.black),
                                    fontFamily: 'montserrat_regular',
                                    decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                                  ),
                                )),
                            ListView.builder(
                                itemCount: requestList[index].questionOptions!.length,
                                physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int subindex) {
                                  return Row(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Radio(
                                          value: 1,
                                          groupValue: radio_value[index],
                                          onChanged: (values) async {
                                            setState(() {
                                              radio_value[index] = 1;
                                              qutionCheckModel[index].response =
                                              "yes";
                                            });
                                          }),
                                      Container(
                                        child: Text(
                                          requestList[index].questionOptions![subindex],
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 14,
                                            color: HexColor(HexColor.black),
                                            fontFamily: 'montserrat_regular',
                                            decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),

                                    ],
                                  );
                                }),
                          ],
                        );
                      }),
                ),
```

[image]

Comment: hey man. i'm looking at this code. In case i have a textfield with controller on the 2nd listview.builder. how do i make the controller unique for each entry? coz i can't do "controller: _controllertext[index][subindex].