# Flutter: How to communicate between two list view in which 1st is on root node and 2nd one is on leaf node

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

Usecase - In my app screen I need a scrollview(outer scrollview) with 3 card(fixed size) the last card contains Tabbarview inside of which I need a scroll view (inner scrollview).

For scrollviews I used Listview.builder.

For more clearance the tree structure is like this ( -> = has a): scroll view -> state object -> container -> column -> TabBarview -> scroll view.

Error - The problem of below code is when I reached to the top of the inner listview view the outer listview supposed to scroll but it is not scrolling.

In other word outter scrollview is not notified by the inner scrollview to move. They are unable to communicate.

I already tried :
1 Give common Scrollcontroller to both Listviews.

2 I also tried Listview.custom with slivers.

```
ScrollController scrollController =ScrollController();

class Share extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      key: PageStorageKey<String>('botttomTabbar1'),
      color: BgColor,
      child: ListView.custom(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 10,
          vertical: 10,
        ),
        controller: scrollController,
        childrenDelegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
          (context,index){
                return SharableLinks();
    },childCount: 1   
 ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SharableLinks extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _SharableLinksSate();
  }
}

class _SharableLinksSate extends State<SharableLinks>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  List<PopularLinkData> data = List();
  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    data.add(PopularLinkData(
      descrption: 'Description.............',
      heading: 'Headline goes here',
      viewCount: 234,
    ));
    _tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose

    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build

    return Container(

      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 35),
      height: 386,

      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
        boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
          BoxShadow(
              color: Color(0xFFC6D0EB),
              blurRadius: 8,
              offset: Offset(0, 4)
          )
        ],
      ),

      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TabBar(
            indicatorWeight: .0001,
            labelPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
            controller: _tabController,
            tabs: <Tab>[
              Tab(
                child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(10)),
                  child: Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    color: _selectedIndex == 0 ? Colors.white : Color(0xFFD8DDEB),

                    child: Text(
                      'Popular',
                      style: TextStyle(color: PrimaryTextColor,
                        fontSize: 18,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Tab(
                child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(10)),
                  child: Container(
                    height: double.infinity,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    color: _selectedIndex == 1 ? Colors.white : Color(0xFFD8DDEB),
                    child: Text(
                      'Generate',
                      style: TextStyle(color: PrimaryTextColor,
                        fontSize: 18,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
            onTap: _onItemTapped,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(

              child: TabBarView(
                key: PageStorageKey<String>('linksTabBar'),
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                controller: _tabController,

                children: <Widget>[
                ,
                ScrollConfiguration(

                  behavior: MyBehavior(),
                  child:
                  ListView.builder(
                    controller:scrollController,

                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return _populerLinks(data[index]);
                    },
                    itemCount: data.length,
                  ),
                ),
                _generateLinks(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use NestedScrollView or CustomScrollView,
See this for reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/45274055/7807311

Comment: I already tried nested view and custom view which allow me to scroll a view inside another scroll view which also happen in my code but my design is much more complex due to which inner scroll view not able to notify outter scroll view to move.

Comment: For more clearance the tree structure is like this ( -> = has a):                                   scroll view -> state<T> -> container -> column -> TabBarview -> scroll view.