# ListView.builder inside another ListView.builder flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, dart

I have a `ListView.builder` that has a dropdown arrow to the right such that when its tapped, it shows another `listView.builder` with its items. The first list works well as it takes the size of its child items but the same experience is not happening on the second list. I have tried every solution but its still not working as I get an error.

**Code**

```
  Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 30,
              ),
              Text(
                "SELECT A PACKAGE",
                textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 12,
                  fontFamily: 'Lato',
                  color: textColor,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 14,
              ),
              !isDataLoaded?ShimmerListView():
                  Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      itemCount: bloc.packages.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index){
                        return Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5),
                          child: Card(
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.
                                all(Radius.circular(12)),
                                side: BorderSide(color:
                                borderColor, width: 1)
                            ),
                            child: Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 16),
                              child:  Row(
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                children: [
                                  Column(
                                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        bloc.packages[index].title,
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 16,
                                          fontFamily: 'Lato',
                                          color: primaryColor,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        height: 14,
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        bloc.packages[index].desc,
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 14,
                                          fontFamily: 'Lato',
                                          color: textColor,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      bloc.packages[index].isTapped?
                                      Container(
                                        height: 300,
                                        child: ListView.builder(
                                          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                          shrinkWrap: true,
                                          itemCount: bloc.packages[globalIndex].plans.length,
                                          itemBuilder: (context, index){
                                          return Container(
                                            width: 230,
                                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 14),
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric
                                              (horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                color:containerBgColor,
                                                borderRadius: BorderRadius
                                                    .all(Radius.circular(12))
                                            ),
                                            child: Row(
                                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                              children: [
                                                Container(
                                                  width:24,
                                                  height:24,
                                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                    color: Colors.white,
                                                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                                SizedBox(
                                                  width: 16,
                                                ),
                                                Column(
                                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                                  children: [
                                                    Text(
                                                      bloc.packages[index].desc,
                                                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                        fontSize: 14,
                                                        fontFamily: 'Lato',
                                                        color: textColor,
                                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                    SizedBox(
                                                      height: 10,
                                                    ),
                                                    Text(
                                                      'NGN ${12000}',
                                                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                        fontSize: 16,
                                                        fontFamily: 'Lato',
                                                        color: normalText,
                                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          );
                                          },
                                        ),
                                      )
                                          :Container(),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  Spacer(),
                                  IconButton(icon:
                                  Icon(
                                   !bloc.packages[index].isTapped?
                                   Mdi.chevronDown:
                                   Mdi.chevronUp,
                                    color: textColor,
                                  ), onPressed:(){
                                    setState(() {
                                      globalIndex = index;
                                      bloc.packages[index].isTapped
                                      = !bloc.packages[index].isTapped;
                                    });
                                  })
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
            ],
          ),
```

**Error**

```
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#87e06 relayoutBoundary=up27 NEEDS-PAINT
```

Tried wrapping second list with an expanded and also give fixed height but got same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ListView` requires a finite height, but your inner `ListView` has an infinite height.
One way you can do it is to wrap the inner `ListView` with a `Container`, `SizedBox`, or any widget with a defined height

example

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('title'),
    ),
    body: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 20,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        if (index == 10) {
          return Container(
            height: 200,  // finite height
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 20,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Container(
                  height: 30,
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(10, 255, index * 10, 100),
                  child: Text(index.toString()),
                );
              },
            ),
          );
        }
        return Container(
          height: 36,
          color: Color.fromRGBO(index * 10, 20, 100, 100),
          child: Text(index.toString()),
        );
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

if you want a cleaner way check out the [`NestedScrollView`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/NestedScrollView-class.html), and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45274055/12571630) to a similar question.

---

#### Edit: `'constraints.hasBoundedWidth': is not true.` error

you need to provide a finite width for `ListView`. your `ListView` is in a row, which has an infinite width.

to fix it, edit the row in line 39 as follows.

```
Row(
  children: [
    Expanded( // 1- Wrap the Column with an Expanded
      child: Column(
        // ...
      ),
    ),
    // Spacer(), 2- Remove Spacer
    IconButton(
      // ...
    ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: added height to inner list view. same result

Comment: @customapps ok I tested your code and it's the same problem, but this time for the width. you need to provide a finite width for `ListView`. your `ListView` is in a row, which has an infinite width. I updated the answer to fix it.