# Can i use listview.builder in listview.builder

Tags: flutter, listview

[Image my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvLWC.png)
can you help me rewrite code by listview.builder in flutter with data

i got problem with listview.builder and row, and listview.builder inside listview.builder. i want rewrite this code with data to show list attributes and option.

and my data "attributes": [
{
"id": 2,
"name": "Choose 1",
"options": [
"Option 1",
"Option 2"
]
},
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Choose 2",
"options": [
"Option 3",
"Option 4"
]
}
]

```html
void _showBottomSheetAtribute(context, ProductModel product){
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (context){
          return Container(
            height: 300,
            child: ListView(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              children: [
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 24, top: 24),
                  child: Text(
                    "Product Customize",
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 24, right: 24),
                    child: Divider()
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 24, top: 16),
                  child: Text(
                    "Type",
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                  child: Container(
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                left: 12,
                                right: 12,
                                top: 8,
                                bottom: 8),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: false
                                  ? AppColors.primaryColor
                                  : Colors.transparent,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                              border:
                              Border.all(color: AppColors.primaryColor, width: 1),
                            ),
                            child: Text(
                              "Option",
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                left: 12,
                                right: 12,
                                top: 8,
                                bottom: 8),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: true
                                  ? AppColors.primaryColor
                                  : Colors.transparent,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                              border:
                              Border.all(color: AppColors.primaryColor, width: 1),
                            ),
                            child: Text(
                              "Bột",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: AppColors.greyColor,
                                letterSpacing: 0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 10, left: 20, right: 20),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: AppColors.primaryColor,
                      minimumSize: Size(200, 50),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      _showBottomSheetGoCart(context);
                    },
                    child:
                    const Text(
                      'Chọn Mua',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 14.0,
                          fontFamily: 'SF Pro Display',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }
    );
  }
```

Comment: there is only single list on your code snippet .

Comment: can you add an image that you would like to archive?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/45270900/10157127

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont you try ExpansionPanel widget?

Comment: i don't think ExpansionPanel  good in my case

Comment: You can try list of PopUpMenuButtons too if you want for the drawer search multi level drawer in pub.dev